# LeafletJS invalid GeoJSON object

Tags: angular, leaflet

I'm working with Leaflet trying to get some GeoJSON going. Everything fine, map is working, but in DevTools console i have an error with invalid GeoJSON. My component is:

I have getRegionsGeoJson, which return to me geoJSON from some url.

[My DevTools Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2mhw.png)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.regionsGeoJsonSubscription$ = this.mapService.getRegionsGeoJson()
      .subscribe(regionsGeoJson => {
          this.regionsGeoJson = regionsGeoJson;
          this.regionsGeoJsonLoaded = Object.keys(this.regionsGeoJson).length > 0;
          this.statisticsEnabled = true;
          this.hidePreloader();
        }
      );

    // LeafletJS map init
    this.map = L.map('map')
      .setView([-25.441105, -49.276855], 13);

    L.tileLayer
      .provider('OpenStreetMap.Mapnik')
      .addTo(this.map);

    L.geoJSON( {
      style: function (feature) {
        return {color: feature.properties.color};
      }
    }).bindPopup(function (layer) {
      return layer.feature.properties.description;
    }).addTo(this.map);

  }
  hidePreloader() {
    this.preloader.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use tools like http://geojsonlint.com/ to see where your data is not compliant with the GeoJSON spec.

Comment: Your console shows a 404 error on regions.json. Maybe you got the URL wrong.

Comment: i have fixed errors 404 and 502, but other errors still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L.geoJSON` factory expects its first argument to be your GeoJSON data, or null if you will be providing it later with `addData` method.

The error you see is because it tries to interpret your optuons object as a GeoJSON objetc, and obviously fails.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
L.geoJSON(this.regionsGeoJson <-- solution {
  style: function (feature) {
    return {color: feature.properties.color};
  }
}).bindPopup(function (layer) {
  return layer.feature.properties.description;
}).addTo(this.map);
```